# C# Break Other Function Loop in Another Function

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, serial-port

I am having two functions - one is runs some commands on my serial port within a loop, the other one is an event handler that should stop the execution of the loop in the first method. Here is some sample code.

```
public void btm_Processing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    for (int i = 1; i <= x ; i++)
    {
        // My processing commands are here .
    }
}
```

And here is my stop button event handler.

```
private void btm_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to stop processing?",
                                       "Error",
                                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Here is where I want to break that loop.                
    }
    else
    {
        // Do other things.                           
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this would be to use a BackgroundWorker thread to execute your loop, then you can cancel it later from the main thread later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

The easier way would be the make a global variable that you set

```
private volatile bool isWorking = false;
public void btm_Processing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isWorking = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x ; i++)
    {
        //My Processing Commands are Here 
        if(!isWorking)
            break;
    }
}

private void btm_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Stop Processing ? ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    isWorking = dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a break variable;

```
private volatile bool shouldStop = false;

private void btm_Processing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    for (int i = 1; i <= x ; i++)
    {
        //My Processing Commands are Here 

        if (shouldStop)
        {
            shouldStop=false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void btm_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to stop processing?",
                                       "Error",
                                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        shouldStop = true;                
    }
    else
    {    
        // Do other things.
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to handle this from my Stop Button how can i handle it there?

Comment: If you're going to use a variable, you'd at least want it to be `volatile`

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare thanks, I've updated the example with your suggestion.

Comment: the problem is After Stop the Program, i cant re run the processing Function!

Comment: You can - just set `shouldStop` back to `false` after exiting the loop.

Comment: @DanielBruckner or that :)

Comment: No... After Stopping it goes to my Waiting Function and not returning back to the process function and waiting for the new command! is there any other way to call back the processing function or going back to the beginning of the Main() ?!

Comment: Well i Found What was Wrong, i have another Thread Loop have to change the status of that one too!